# Cloud Function post request not sending error message properly to IOS app

Tags: swift, http, post, google-cloud-functions, urlsession

I have an iOS app receiving json data from a google cloud function.

The data is retrieved and works perfectly when there is no error.

However, when the cloud function returns an error, the function below recognizes **error** as **nil**

**Client:**

```
func initialize() {

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String,
                let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String else {
                
                ///////////   
               //ERROR is not being recognized
                /////////

           let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to decode response from server."
           print("Error loading page: \(message)")
                    return
       }
})
task.resume()
}
```

**Client Output:**

> Failed to decode response from server.

**Server:**

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myFunction')(message)
    .then(result => {
    // this works perfectly and is recognized by the swift function //
    res.send({publishableKey: publishableKey, clientSecret: clientSecret});
})
.catch(err => {
    // this is not recognized by the swift function //
     console.log(err) // full of data
    return res.status(400).send({error: err});
});
```

**Logs(for error case):**

> Function execution took 240 ms, finished with status code: 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requests fails I think that your error will come into the response parameter and you have to decode it. I think that the error parameter will be different than nil only if the server can't be reached or function does not exist. So basically in the else clause you will have to search into the response parameter for error.

Comment: So your saying send a JSON object from the cloud function with the same parameters for each case success and error? Im thinking I add error to each json object and fill it with nil if no error.

Comment: I think that the client side is interpreting "return res.status(400).send({error: err});" as a response not as an error. And it is going into the else clause because it can't decode json["clientSecret"] and json["publishableKey"]

Comment: ok let me test. I have a feeling you are right.